# Updating wifi credentials to wpa_supplicant.conf in Rasberry Pi using Node.js

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to provide wifi details to raspberry pi though Bluetooth.

We are adding the wifi credentials to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Once I get the credentials I am using nodejs to update the wifi credentials using fs.write(). I am completely overwriting the file. I am providing all the details needed in the file.

But I am getting the following error :

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

But when open the file in nano/vim I see that the file is getting written correctly. Am i missing something? My guess is that it might be the format in which I am writing.

I have an other question:
What will happen if I keep on appending the file with the wifi credentials, instead of overwriting it?

Any help is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem why we were not able to provide wifi details. The reason was we were not writing the file properly. When creating the network variable, we were adding a space.

Error causing conf:

```
network={
        ssid ="WifiName"
        psk ="password"
}
```

Correct conf:

```
network={
        ssid="WifiName"
        psk="password"
}
```